# Printing from matlab workspace to a C file - getting names of the variable

Tags: c, matlab, variables, matrix, file-generation

I am generating a C header file from Matlab using the Matlab workspace variables. For that I am using a vector of the matrices, each matrix corresponds to one .h file.
I need the variables' names for changing the comments/filenames based on the usage of a particular matrix in a loop.

So I would have:

```matlab
matrix = {A, B, C};

for any_matrix = matrix
   fprintf(file, '#ifndef %s_INCLUDED\n#define %s_INCLUDED\n\n', variable_name, variable_name)
   ...
   % rest of the code using the values of the variables
end
```

How can I access the information about the variable name to put it in the placeholder?

Comment: This is not actual MATLAB code. Why don’t you write the bit that you know how to do, so that we can see what you do and don’t understand. It will make it easier to help you. Do I need to show you how to write a loop in MATLAB? Do I need to show you how to write a string to a file?

Comment: @Cris Luengo, I just would like to know how to access the variable name, not the value as I need to substitute it in the fprintf fcn, the rest of the code is not relevant.

Comment: Here's the thing: you can't access the variable name normally, but you can in some very specific circumstances (e.g. you can get the name of variables passed into a function). But there is a different way to solve your problem: list the variable names, then fetch their contents. But to show you how to do this, I'd need to write a bunch of code for you. If there's already some code up, all I need to do is change it, which is a lot easier. You don't need to post all of your code, but if the bit of pseudo-code you posted were actual code, I'd have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the name of a variable in a context such as this. But if you reverse your logic, you can get there: list the names of the variables you want to export, then in the loop fetch the value of each of those variables.

[`eval` is considered bad practice](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56124-eval-is-evil-using-variables-created-dynamically-info-retrieval), but in a use case like this it is actually really useful.

This is how I'd do it:

```matlab
variables = ["A", "B", "C"];
for name = variables
   value = eval(name);
   % use `name` and `value` here.
end
```

If this is a function, and you call the function with `export_my_vars(["A", "B", "C"])`, then you won't have access to those variables and `eval` will fail. In this case, use `evalin(...,'caller')` instead.

Comment: I found another solution, I've created a struct in Matlab for each of the matrices, and I am passing the information about the variable inside the mat.name, on the other hand, mat.data contains the numerical values, and the vector matrix = {mat, mat2, mat3} etc. It works in the given setup hence I will leave it this way.